# MySQL - Slow Performing Subquery when DISTINCT Is Used

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, optimization, mysql-8.0

I have this query that runs very slowly when `DISTINCT` is used;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT query_text FROM search_query WHERE (store_id IN (1)) AND (num_results > 0) ORDER BY popularity desc LIMIT 100) AS result WHERE (result.query_text = '<search_term>');
```

If I run this query as is, it takes between three and four seconds. However, if I remove `DISTINCT`, results are functionally instant. However, I can't simply *remove* that `DISTINCT` from the equation since this query needs to gather a distinct list of 100 search terms with no repeats. Since this is part of a Magento install, `store_id` could be a list of multiple store IDs. While the current setup is single store, this could change so I'd rather leave the `DISTINCT` as it sits.

This is the create table statement;

```
CREATE TABLE `search_query` (
  `query_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Query ID',
  `query_text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Query text',
  `num_results` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Num results',
  `popularity` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Popularity',
  `redirect` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Redirect',
  `store_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `display_in_terms` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Display in terms',
  `is_active` smallint DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Active status',
  `is_processed` smallint DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Processed status',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Updated at',
  PRIMARY KEY (`query_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `SEARCH_QUERY_QUERY_TEXT_STORE_ID` (`query_text`,`store_id`),
  KEY `SEARCH_QUERY_QUERY_TEXT_STORE_ID_POPULARITY` (`query_text`,`store_id`,`popularity`),
  KEY `SEARCH_QUERY_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `SEARCH_QUERY_IS_PROCESSED` (`is_processed`),
  KEY `SEARCH_QUERY_STORE_ID_POPULARITY` (`store_id`,`popularity`),
  CONSTRAINT `SEARCH_QUERY_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

And this is what `EXPLAIN` returns;

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT query_text FROM search_query WHERE (store_id IN (1)) AND (num_results > 0) ORDER BY popularity desc LIMIT 100) AS result WHERE (result.query_text = '<search_term>');
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                       | key                   | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>   | NULL       | ref  | <auto_key0>                                                                                                                         | <auto_key0>           | 768     | const |     10 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | search_query | NULL       | ref  | SEARCH_QUERY_QUERY_TEXT_STORE_ID,SEARCH_QUERY_QUERY_TEXT_STORE_ID_POPULARITY,SEARCH_QUERY_STORE_ID,SEARCH_QUERY_STORE_ID_POPULARITY | SEARCH_QUERY_STORE_ID | 2       | const | 460386 |    33.33 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I tried creating a different covering index, but it didn't help. This is the covering index I made (and subsequently forced the query to use);

```
ALTER TABLE `search_query` ADD INDEX `QUERY_PERFORMANCE_FIX_TEST_INDEX` (`store_id`, `num_results`, `popularity` desc, `query_text`);
```

That helped a little but not by much. A difference of a couple hundred ms at best so that won't be the solution. Without this index and without `DISTINCT`, the results are nearly instant so I don't think it's necessarily the indexes *being wrong*, but, perhaps, a missing one?

Am I missing an index (such as a `FULLTEXT` index on `query_text`)? Is there a better way of determining this information?

Comment: That query is somewhat meaningless -- If there are two rows the the same `query_text`, and they have different `popularity` values, which value should be used for sorting?

Comment: Would it work to move `query_text = '<search_term>'` into the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Marisa,
Try this, please

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT query_text FROM search_query WHERE (store_id IN (1)) AND 
        (num_results > 0) AND (query_text = '<search_term>') 
        ORDER BY popularity desc LIMIT 100) AS result;
```

NOT TESTED.
Let us know your results, please.

Comment: That won't work for this situation. I have to have the search query outside of the subquery, otherwise it won't fit the logic. It's meant to determine if a particular search term is in the most popular 100 terms or not. It's part of a search suggestion functionality.

Comment: Marisa, Please run this query to determine Maximum and Average Length of some of your columns used in search_query.

Comment: # sel-mmaMLALsearch_query.sql    min max avg last upd 2023-11-08 WLH
#      original 2023-11-08 WLH
    SELECT 
    'Begin Time',NOW(),DATABASE(),' ',COUNT(*),' ', 
    
 
 
 
 MIN(query_id),MAX(query_id),AVG(query_id),MAX(LENGTH(query_id)),AVG(LENGTH(query_id)),'query_id',' ', 
    
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 MIN(query_text),MAX(query_text),AVG(query_text),MAX(LENGTH(query_text)),AVG(LENGTH(query_text)),'query_text',' ', 
            FROM search_query \G; 
    SELECT 'End   Time',NOW();